# How do I create a Button in HTML that restart the script

Tags: html

I need to Add a ‘Try again’ button to the html section of the ‘Guessgame.html’ file and amend the script to run when it is clicked.
This is what I have right now:

```js
var target = 8;
var guess = prompt("I’m an integer between 1 and 10\n Guess me", 0);
var result = (guess == target) ? "Brilliant! Good guess." : "Sorry your guess was wrong.";
document.write(result);
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0000ff
}
```

```html
<title>Javascript template</title>
<div align="center">
  <h1>Beginning Javascript</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend starting with a basic guide like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics). It's talking about functions and events when you get far enough and has nice examples.

Comment: I clicked the `[<>]` snippet editor for you and filled in the panes with the code to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the script inside a function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript template</title>
    <style>
    h1 {font-family:serif; font-size:36px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center}
    h2 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#000000; text-align:center}
    h3 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#0000ff}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="result" align="center">
    <h1>Beginning Javascript</h1>
     </div>
     
     <button onclick=run()>Restart</button>
    
    <script>
function run(){

    var target = 8;
    var guess = prompt ("I’m an integer between 1 and 10\n Guess me", 0);
    var result = (guess == target) ? "Brilliant! Good guess.":"Sorry your guess was wrong.";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (result);}
    run();
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try this twice!

Comment: It worked, but once you click the restart button once, it doesn't take you back to the original page, and doesn't give you the restart button again. Is there anyway to make it loop like that

Comment: @JakeNyugen - how come you accept this answer when it actually does not do everything you want and is not using Best Practices. Is it because you understand this answer better than mine?

Comment: @mplungjan Your formula does everything I need it to do, but in this assignment I'm not allowed to use anything apart from simple code.

Comment: What is simple? `<button type="button" onclick="run()">Restart</button>` is simple but not best practices. It is however 50% better code than `<button onclick=run()>Restart</button>` since as soon as you wrap your button in a form, its default action is to submit the form, not to run the code so the page is reloaded.

Comment: Also when you restart, 8 is the same number over and over

Comment: @JakeNyugen Anyway - I updated my answer to have a simpler version

Answer (score 2):

1. NEVER use document.write after the page has loaded
2. Create a button and add an event listener:

```js
function init() {
  var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var guess = prompt("I’m an integer between 1 and 10\n Guess me", 0);
  var result = (guess == target) ? "Brilliant! Good guess." : "Sorry your guess was wrong.";
  document.querySelector("#res").innerText = result;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded 
  document.querySelector("#but").addEventListener("click", init);
  // init(); // uncomment this if you want the question to show when page loads too
})
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0000ff
}
```

```html
<title>Javascript template</title>
<div align="center">
  <h1>Beginning Javascript</h1>

  <button id="but" type="button">Hit me</button><br/>
  <span id="res"></span>
</div>
```

Simpler version if you only want one number per page load and insist on inline event handling which is not recommended

```js
var target = 8;
function init() {
  var guess = prompt("I’m an integer between 1 and 10\n Guess me", 0);
  var result = (guess == target) ? "Brilliant! Good guess." : "Sorry your guess was wrong.";
  document.querySelector("#res").innerText = result;
}
init();
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0000ff
}
```

```html
<title>Javascript template</title>
<div align="center">
  <h1>Beginning Javascript</h1>

  <button id="but" type="button" onclick="init()">Restart</button><br/>
  <span id="res"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works, but the generated number is **not** an integer. Use `var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;`